# How to change Ip Adress of Magento

Tags: networking, server, magento

i have installed Magento 2.2 on my Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS and during installation my ipadress was 192.xxx.xxx.74 and its working fine with this ipadress . But now for some oragnizational reasons i want to change my ipadress to 192.xxx.xxx.75. As i am new with this software so i am not getting any solution that i can change the ipadress from 74 to 75. I would be thankfull if anyone can tell me in detail which steps i need to take to change this ipadress and where i can find these config files. Thanks in advance

Comment: The magento website has this to say: https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/m1wiki/pages/14024830/Update+Site+URL+in+core+config+data+after+you+move+to+a+new+server+or+change+domains Does that not work for you? If so why not?

Answer (score 0):

First you open your database that you have created for Magento, then after open the table **core_config_data** of your Magento database.

Change the two paths values 
**From:**

> web/unsecure/base_url = http://192.168.0.74/training/Magento2.1.7/ 
>   web/secure/base_url = https://192.168.0.74/training/Magento2.1.7/

**To:**

> web/unsecure/base_url = http://192.168.0.75/training/Magento2.1.7/ 
>   web/secure/base_url = https://192.168.0.75/training/Magento2.1.7/

where training/Magento2.1.7 is my Magento path.